# WP7 - How to synchronize with a web service?

Tags: synchronization, windows-phone-7, data-synchronization

I'm working on a multi-platform "occassionally connected" app.  Each instance of the app stores a "cache" of the data that it retrieves from the cloud, which has the authoritative datastore.  So on start-up the app would check if its cache is out of date, and if so download the delta from the cloud.  This is certainly do-able in WP7.  What I don't know how to achieve is to send any changes made by the app back to the cloud.  When the user exits the app, in iOS or Android, I would launch a background task to transmit the delta back to the cloud, but with wp7, without that background functionality, I would have to transmit on close, and I could not guarantee that the transmission would finish before the OS killed my app.  Is this just not achievable on WP7 today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options here which you could apply independently or both of.

You could do a more chatty conversation with your server.. ie communicate changes as they are accepted by the user.

You could also have a background process runing while your app is running that sends changes up at periodic intervals.

There may be times when the changes aren't sent up and the app is no longer running. These would be picked up next time the app is running.

I suppose you could describe this as a best effort basis.

Comment: The first option is a bad fit for my case, the user could conceivably be accepting changes once a second, and that would be just a bit too chatty (and hell on my server).  The second option is plausible, but since the app will frequently be used on multiple devices, it will be hard to find a balance between "updates too often and is chatty" and "good chance of not synchronizing a significant chunk of data, and then creating a conflict when another device is used."  So it seems that for now, wp7 is a choice between a bad implementation and no implementation at all.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the types of interactions taking place in your app? Are there different of updates of different natures.. some always done, some sometimes done? Some done frequently, some done infrequently? Are there any page transitions taking place during app usage?

Comment: Its essentially a vocabulary trainer - users "practice" a flashcard and they can also crud their collection of flashcards - so the pages are essentialy two - a "flashcard editor" and a practice screen.  When a flashcard is practiced, the relevant details of that have to be synchronized, as well as any edits to the flashcards.  Flashcard editing will likely happen relatively infrequently, and a user could conceivably "practice" a flashcard once every few seconds.

Comment: So the flashcard crud itself is easy... just sync on infrequent changes once they're confirmed. The practice part I'm not clear on the purpose of syncing this activity, is it just stats so they can see their stats online? If so, you could just have a visual indicator showing sync pending, let them press it to make a sync happen and execute syncs infrequently in the background. Seems solid if that's all that's going on.

Comment: Well the idea of synching the practice data is to enable users to practice on various devices, even on the same day.  For that the practice data needs to be synched, so cards that were shown on a given day aren't shown again.  Your idea about a visual synch pending indicator is a good one, but I would like the entire synching feature to be as hands off and invisible as possible, and a manual button certainly goes against that.

Comment: I understand the goal and agree it's worth looking into options. Sometimes we have to work with what's available to get jobs done. It may also help to influence vNext priorities by posting on the suggestion forum or Connect. If your specific requirements are understood, it may influence 3rd party app multitasking or encourage thinking of other options that would help the scenario.

Comment: You're right, and I certainly intend to make myself heard on the topic. Thanks for the feedback, and helping me feel comfortable with my understanding of the options available to me.